# Reading iframe content doesn't work under Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to use a content of a .txt file on a web page. The problem is that I can't do it easy way (server-side php). I figured out the trick of opening a text file in the iframe and then asking for innerHTML/innerText. It turns out that people were there before - found the following code, much cleaner than my attempts, at https://zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/computers/browsers/extern_via_iframe.html

It works locally under FireFox and IE, but does not under Chrome. How to make it work under Chrome?

```
function getIframeContentText( frameID )
{
    var elt = document.getElementById(frameID);
    //alert( "getIframeContentText:" + elt );
    //alert( "getIframeContentText Content:" + elt.contentDocument );

    if( elt.contentDocument )   // DOM
    {
        var iframe_doc = elt.contentDocument;
        var range = iframe_doc.createRange();

        range.selectNodeContents( iframe_doc.body );
        return range.toString();
   }
   else             // IE6
   {
        var iframe_doc = document.all[frameID].contentWindow.document;
       //return iframe_doc.body.innerHTML; // gets HTML
       return iframe_doc.body.outerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read a cross-domain iframe or a same-domain iframe? If you're trying to do it cross-domain, then the single origin policy is stopping you from doing so.

Comment: same-domain. To be more exact, I'm testing it on a desktop, without loading files to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is because handling iFrames in ie and firefox is differentthan chrome ,because of chromes same-origin policy
start the browser using `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="." --disable-web-security`

and you have to wait for the document to load fully ie all the contents of the page ,it may happen there may be iFrame inside iFrame (for generic solution )

```
$(window).load(function()
        {
                chromeFrameInitializers(document);//for handling frames and IFrames 

        });

        function chromeFrameInitializers(document)
        {
            var frame=document.getElementsByTagName("frame");
            for(var i=0;i<frame.length;i++)
                {
                var subDocFrame=frame[i].contentDocument;
                //do your stuf
                chromeFrameInitializers(subDocFrame)
                }

            var iFrame=document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame");
            for(var i=0;i<iFrame.length;i++)
                {
                var subDocIFrame=iFrame[i].contentDocument;
                //do your stuf
                chromeFrameInitializers(subDocIFrame)
                }
        }
`
```

it handles for both frame and iFrame (recursively ). for this `$(window).load` jquery needed